# In vim airline, only show git branch, not changes to file

Tags: git, vim, vim-airline

I'm using vim with airline. I like that airline shows me the git branch, but I don't want it to show me the lines added/removed/changed. What should I add to my ~/.vimrc file to change that? I know I need to set `g:airline_section_b` but I'm not quite sure what to set it to.

I tried this, but the syntax is clearly wrong, because it didn't work.

```
let g:airline_section_b = airline#section#create(['branch'])
```

Comment: Just a guess, have you installed the GitGutter plugin? Try `:GitGutterDisable`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `:help airline`:

```
-------------------------------------                        *airline-hunks*
vim-gitgutter <https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter>                   
vim-signify <https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify>                          
changesPlugin <https://github.com/chrisbra/changesPlugin>                   

* enable/disable showing a summary of changed hunks under source control.
let g:airline#extensions#hunks#enabled = 1
```

So add

```
let g:airline#extensions#hunks#enabled=0
```

to your `~/.vimrc` and restart `vim`.